# Crystal Report doesn't show data when generated

Tags: crystal-reports, report

When I generate it on runtime, it doesn't show any data. But it does when I check on the 'Main Report Preview' of VS 2010. I have also checked my stored procedure, it does produce data when I execute it. What seems to be the problem?

This is my code in page_load:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string municipio = Request.QueryString["municipio"];
        string ano = Request.QueryString["ano"];
        string cnpj = Server.UrlDecode(Request.QueryString["cnpj"]);

        DataTable dt;

        string CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBCS"].ConnectionString;

        using (SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(CS))
        {

            cnn.Open();
            //stored procedure 
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spConsultaRelatorioCompleto", cnn);

                cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ano", ano);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@municipio", municipio);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cnpj", cnpj);

                //read access to the database
                SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

                    //datatable with data
                    dt = new DataTable("dt");

                    //datatable with datareader's data
                    dt.Load(dr);
                    da.Fill(dt);


        }

        ReportDocument MeuRelatorio = new ReportDocument();
        MeuRelatorio.Load(Server.MapPath("RelatorioConvenio.rpt"));
        MeuRelatorio.SetDataSource(dt);
        CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = MeuRelatorio;




    }



}
```

}

I give some values in another webform when I click the button below:

```
protected void btnExport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Redirect("RelatorioGerado.aspx?municipio=" + ddlmunicipioconvenente.Text + "&cnpj=" + Server.UrlEncode(tbcnpjconvenente.Text) + "&ano=" + tbAno.Text);

    }
```

Comment: when you trace it is the dt filled with values from DB??

Comment: Yes the dt is filled with values from DB

Comment: try to export it using http response? does it at least work? and filled with data.